# Convert text and update in destination sheet using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code that can do the following:

1. Compare two sheets using Dic and update values of sheet "DRG" (Col k) into sheet "Latency" (into Col O) if a match is found.

This is what I want to do, Col K in sheet "DRG" can have only 3 values:

- Approved
- Pended
- In progress

2.When a match is found, instead of inserting the above three values, I want to insert: "Pass" for "Approved", "Fail" for "Pended".

Can someone please guide me here?

```
Sub PassFailValidation()

Dim cl As Range, Dic As Object
Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary"): Dic.Comparemode = vbTextCompare
With Sheets("Latency")
    For Each cl In .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
        If Not Dic.exists(cl.Value) Then Dic.Add cl.Value, cl.Row
    Next cl
End With

With Sheets("DRG")
    For Each cl In .Range("C2:C" & .Cells(Rows.count, "K").End(xlUp).Row) '
        If Dic.exists(cl.Value) Then
            Sheets("Latency").Cells(Dic(cl.Value), 15) = cl.Offset(, 1) '<--| write the values
            Dic.Remove (cl.Value)
        End If
    Next cl
End With
Set Dic = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: are the values in `Sheet("Latency")` column B and `Sheet("DRG")` column C unique ? Do you have 1 value in each of the columns ? I'm asking, cause if that's the case you can use `Application.Match` function, unless you set your mind on using the `Dictionary` ?

Comment: What I'm tying do through Dic is Vlookup. So I'm checking whether values in ""Col B is present in Col C of "DRG"

Comment: I understand that, the question is why ? you want to practice the `Dictionary` ? because a simple `Match` will do the job here

Comment: When I wanted to do this, I found Dic was one way and I just started using this. I didn't know there was another method. If there are other simple method that can do this, I will use it

Comment: show examples of a "before" and "after" scenarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below using the `Application.Match` (tested) :

```
Option Explicit

Sub PassFailValidation()

Dim Rng As Range, cl As Range
Dim LastRow As Long, MatchRow As Variant

With Sheets("DRG")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row '<-- find last row with data in column C
    Set Rng = .Range("C2:C" & LastRow) '<-- set range in Column C
End With

With Sheets("Latency")
    For Each cl In .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row) ' loop through all cells in Column B
        MatchRow = Application.Match(cl.Value, Rng, 0) ' find match with values in Colummn C as in "DRG" sheet
        If Not IsError(MatchRow) Then ' <-- successful match

            Select Case Sheets("DRG").Range("K" & MatchRow + 1).Value
                Case "Approved"
                    .Range("O" & cl.Row).Value = "Pass"

                Case "Pended"
                    .Range("O" & cl.Row).Value = "Fail"

                Case "In progress"
                    .Range("O" & cl.Row).Value = "In progress"                
            End Select
        End If
    Next cl
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a small question, how do i search using col names instead of col alphabet. Ex: lets say col B has the name as "TestB" and Col O has the name as "TestO"?. Just asking so that even if the col gets changed, the code can search using the col name

Comment: Not sure I understand, what is col name ? Can you tell me in which of my code line you want it implemented ?

Comment: sorry if i'm not clear. For example each col will have an heading (in row 1 ) Lets say Col A's heading will be "S.No" and this will be present in "A1". So if i refer my code to check in "Col A" for serial number and if someone changed it then the code will throw up error. Instead if I refer using the name of the col, "S.No" in this case, even if the order is changed, the code will use the col which has "S.No" written. In the above code, I want to change it wherever the col has been referred.

Comment: @stackmark  this is entirely different, to find the column by name, you need to first use .Find for each header, then use the result for the rest of the code. If you need this you should open a new post, describe what you need, your modified code, and other users including me can assist you

Comment: @stackmark  thanks for accepting my answer, I'll look for your next post to see if I can help

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
Sub PassFailValidation()

    Dim cl As Range, Dic As Object
    Dim v, s

    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary"): Dic.Comparemode = vbTextCompare
    With Sheets("Latency")
        For Each cl In .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
            If Not Dic.exists(cl.Value) Then Dic.Add cl.Value, cl.Row
        Next cl
    End With

    With Sheets("DRG")
        For Each cl In .Range("C2:C" & .Cells(Rows.count, "K").End(xlUp).Row) 
            v = cl.Value
            If Dic.exists(v) Then
                Select Case cl.Offset(, 1).Value
                    Case "Approved": s = "Pass"
                    Case "Pended": s = "Fail"
                    Case Else: s = ""
                End If
                Sheets("Latency").Cells(Dic(v), 15) = s 
                Dic.Remove (v)
            End If
        Next cl
    End With
    Set Dic = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I was a little confused trying to follow some of your logic without being able to see the data but see code below that I tested and worked, hopefully if I misunderstood slightly what you were trying to do it is close and clear enough for you to be able to tweak it slightly and get it working...

```
Public Sub sampleCode()
Dim lookupRange As Range
Dim lookupArr() As Variant
Dim searchRange As Range
Dim rowCounter As Long
Dim matchResult As Variant

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Latency")
    Set lookupRange = .Range("B2:B" & .Range(.UsedRange.address)(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1).Row)
End With
lookupArr = lookupRange

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DRG")
    Set searchRange = .Range("C2:C" & .Range(.UsedRange.address)(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1).Row)
End With

For rowCounter = 1 To UBound(lookupArr, 1)
    Set searchResult = customFind(searchRange, lookupArr(rowCounter, 1))
    If TypeName(searchResult) = "Range" Then
        Select Case searchResult(1, 9).Text
            Case Is = "Approved"
                lookupRange(rowCounter, 14).Formula = "Pass"
            Case Is = "Pended"
                lookupRange(rowCounter, 14).Formula = "Fail"
        End Select
    End If
Next   
End Sub

Public Function customFind(searchRange As Range, lookupVal As Variant) As Variant
On Error GoTo fail:
Set customFind = searchRange.Find(lookupVal)
Exit Function
fail:
End Function
```

N.B.- As you can see I moved the find function into a support function- this is because Find frequently returns errors and VBA's error handling options within the main sub are weak if you ask me, and any robust EH'ing would likely require duplicating function/sub calls, so I use very simple support functions like above to do my error handling with one function call and no surprises..
Also, if you are searching a very large number of cells and speed is becoming an issue I would switch to all arrays but I didn't in above example because it would really be overkill for most small-medium scale situations.

Hope this helps,
TheSilkCode